# What does そこんところ mean?

Tags: anime

In JoJo's Bizarre Adventure anime, Stardust Crusaders arc, episode 3, a person （花京院｛かきょういん｝）　who JoJo (the protagonist) just saved, asks JoJo why he did that, to which JoJo replies

> さあ、**そこんとこ**だが、俺もよく分からん.

Later on, JoJo asks 花京院 why he decided to join him, to which 花京院 also replies

> **そこんところ**だが。なぜ同行したくなったのかは 私にもよく分からないんだがね。

What does it mean? "This and that" (no particular reason)?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Both 「そこ**ん**とこ」 and 「そこ**ん**ところ」 are colloquial pronunciations of:

> 「そこ**の**ところ」

This is a very common expression which means "***the point (that has just been) raised***".

You would need to memorize 「そこんとこ」, etc. to be able to use them naturally because you simply **will not** arrive at them by directly translating any English phrases.

These phrases are often followed immediately by 「だが」、「ですが」, 「なんだけど」, etc. making the whole phrase mean "***Regarding the point raised(, though,)***".

Comment: Another common related idiom; そこんとこよろしく！
It's added at the end of requests, with the implication being please don't brush over it / ignore it.